# charset issue during inserting data

Tags: php, mysql, kohana

I have a strange problem, when I'm inserting data into the database.

When I'm passing the value from form field in English, everything works as expected (the value is inserted). However, when I pass the value in another language (e.g. Russian), the value inserts, but it is empty in database table. Not null, just an empty value.

I am using the [Kohana framework](http://kohanaframework.org/). I have tried to set the proper charset with `mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");`, but it doesn't work, and the table data in the database is set as `utf8` and `utf8_general_ci`.

Anybody knows how to solve this issue?

Hey guys, I just found out that the problem in my Controller, the incoming parameters are in wrong charset.
Here is the output result: ��� �������
Does anybody know how to set charset in Kohana controller?

Comment: `<meta charset="utf-8">`?

Comment: yes, <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

Comment: Could you show some code? At DB-level, what's the charset of your table?

Comment: charset in my db set as utf8 and utf8_general_ci

Comment: i just found out that the problem in my Controller, the incoming parameters are in wrong charset : here is the output result ��� ������� Anybody knows how to set charset in Kohana controller?